# Show hints when writing function

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

sometimes when I write `function` in AndroidStudio/Intellij the hint disappear. How to restore it with a keyboard shortcut?
Screenshot below.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, you can follow these steps:

> File >> Settings >> Editor >> General >> Code Completion

You can enable `Basic Completion` and `Smart Type Completion`.

[image]

---

For Mac OS, you can change the keyboard shortcuts.

> System Preferences >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts >> Spotlight

You can disable `Show Spotlight search` and assign a new key.